# Material-UI RadioGroup - no way to recognise a click on currently selected Radio

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to set up a Material-ui `<RadioGroup>` for a survey tool without a submit button. I want the selection to be processed when the `<Radio>` is clicked. Using RadioGroup's `onChange()` this works fine if there is no Radio selected yet. But if I go backwards through the survey, the previous questions have their Radio pre-selected. In this case, when I click the Radio that is already selected, `onChange()` does not fire so I can't move forward to the next question.

I've tried using `onClick()` instead, but this only works if the user clicks the Radio button. If they click the label instead, the event value is undefined.

Comment: from a ux perspective, it is better to have another call to action to proceed to the next step, rather then having to click the already selected radio

Comment: <Radio> onClick event fired on radio and label click. What version of the react material-ui are you using?

Comment: May you provide some sample code in the codesandbox.io which will reproduce this behavior?

Comment: Material core 4.9.13